# Is it ok to edit .git/config file in repository manually?

Tags: git, git-config

I used to edit `.git/config` file manually, for example adding repositories, setting upstream repository etc. based on how it looked in other `.git/config` files. My colleague advised me not to do it, because I can make a mess there (as a general rule, not based on something I did). He told me to use commands, which is harder for me, because I always have to check them. I prefer to benefit from "everything is a file" unix approach. I also see better what is going on, because I have the whole picture when looking at the file.

I'm not proficient at git and I usually make a lot of mess, but I think it's not because of editing `.git/config` files, mostly it happens when I try to resolve conflicts.

Is it generally not advised to edit these files manually?

Comment: As long as you know what you are doing, it is fine.

Comment: What are you looking for here? How would you know the "right" answer if you hear it? Are you just hoping for "permission"?

Comment: Note that `git config --edit` brings up your configured editor (core.editor, `$GIT_EDITOR`, etc) *on* the config file. So Git doesn't specifically encourage it (there's nothing in the documentation saying "do that") but definitely doesn't *dis*-courage it either as it provides a direct way to invoke the editor.

Comment: @matt I wonder if it is common thing to do it or not and if are there some disadvantages.

Comment: The "disadvantages" are obvious and you already know exactly what they are. I return to the question I asked before: what you are you looking for _here?_ This is not a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's syntactically valid, that's fine. I usually find it faster to open the file in a text editor and edit it that way, too.